# How to use the results of one table found using form params to query another table - Ruby on Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I need to use the result of a query, found using form parameters to query another table and I am having difficulties.

The first query is:

```
       @criteria_event = CriteriaEvent.joins(:events).where("events.horse_id = ? AND events.task_group_id = ? AND events.start_date = ?", criteria_event_params[:horse_id], criteria_event_params[:task_group_id], criteria_event_params[:start_date])
```

This query returns the correct information as follows:

```
    [#<CriteriaEvent id: 57, task_group_id: 3, start_time: "2000-01-01 10:00:00", created_at: "2016-02-12 01:36:54", updated_at: "2016-02-12 01:36:54", start_date: "2016-02-23", horse_id: 13>]>
```

I have been trying to return the related events using the CriteriaEvent id: found above (id:57) in the following query.  This query follows the above query immediately:

```
   @events = Event.where(criteria_event_id: @criteria_event.id)
```

I get the following error:

```
  NoMethodError (undefined method `id' for #<CriteriaEvent::ActiveRecord_Relation:
```

The relevant models have the following:

```
  class CriteriaEvent < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :events
      accepts_nested_attributes_for :events
  end

  class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :criteria_event
   end
```

The controller has the following permits:

```
   def criteria_event_params
       params.require(:criteria_event).permit(:horse_id, :task_group_id, :start_date, :start_time, events_attributes: [:id, :criteria_event_id])
   end


   def event_params
      params.require(:event).permit(:title, :start_date, :start_time, :end_date, :end_time, :location, :description, :notification_type, :notification_span_before, :notification_span_type, :horse_id, :task_group_id, :criteria_event_id, criteria_events_attributes: [:criteria_event_id, :id])
   end
```

What am I missing?

Thanking you in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> NoMethodError (**undefined method `id'** for #

The issue is that `@criteria_event` contains multiple records (inside an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object). This works like an array, and as such you don't have access to `id` on its own.

Instead, you'll need to *either* use [`pluck(:id)`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck) to get an array of ids, or just [`find_by`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find_by) (only returning a single result):

```
#pluck
@criteria_event = CriteriaEvent.joins(:events).where(events: { horse_id: criteria_event_params[:horse_id], task_group_id: criteria_event_params[:task_group_id], start_date criteria_event_params[:start_date]}).pluck(:id)

#find_by
@criteria_event = CriteriaEvent.joins(:events).find_by(events: { horse_id: criteria_event_params[:horse_id], task_group_id: criteria_event_params[:task_group_id], start_date: criteria_event_params[:start_date] }).id
```

Both of these will then allow you to use:

```
@events = Event.where(criteria_event_id: @criteria_event)
```

Comment: I don't know why I wait so long to ask a questions.   You guys & gals are wonderful.   I have been struggling with this for about a week.   Thanks very, very much!

Answer (score 2):

Hey you are trying to select `id` on active record relation you can use  `map` for array of `id` as,

```
 @events = Event.where(criteria_event_id: @criteria_event.map(&:id))
```

Instead of using separate query you can find Events in this way,

```
@events= Event.joins(:criteria_event).where("events.horse_id = ? AND events.task_group_id = ? AND events.start_date = ?", criteria_event_params[:horse_id], criteria_event_params[:task_group_id], criteria_event_params[:start_date])
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Vishal. This also works.   I would have liked to "ticked" both responses.